# How to avoid connection rejected message on embed script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm recently using the App Script to get some usage between an app and google docs.
The script is working fine when I implement it as a web app, but when I try to embed the code in another web I get the message "script.google.com has rejected the connection". I can't find the solution anywhere, so I hope someone could help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you show your script? See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this option on your HtmlOutput:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode

It allows any site to display the web app in an iFrame, something that is disabled by default.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. My problem is I don´t have this lane anywhere HtmlService.createHtmlOutput so I don't know where to use the XFrameOptions. I can give you the code of the Code.gs file if that could help.